# Want to delete all the backup data in the deja dup folder but I have forgotten the password

Tags: backup, deja-dup

The backup in Ubuntu 14.04 is eating away all my disk space. All I want is to delete all that backup altogether (all the files in deja-dup) but I can't remember the encryption key I used then. I tried using the following command but my passphrase was still wrong:

```
duplicity remove-older-than 2017-09-31 file:///home/$USER/deja-dup/ --force
```

This is what the command line looks like:

```
shamininski@shamininski-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ duplicity remove-older-than 2017-09-31 file:///home/$USER/deja-dup/ --force
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
GnuPG passphrase: 
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20170907T033748Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: bad key
===== End GnuPG log =====

shamininski@shamininski-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ^C
shamininski@shamininski-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: What `keyword` is this?

Comment: Which password are you talking about? Since when does one need a password to destroy data?

Comment: @George and David Foerster - I mean the encryption key,  plus I tried deleting using the following command from the command line but I was still asked of a pass phrase to which I wasn't successful to match the correct one or whatever it wanted.

Comment: @David Foerster,  the comment above is for you too. Thanks!

Comment: Did you add sudo to the delete command?

Comment: @George, I have tried it with sudo but still, this is what I get,  a bad key!

Comment: @George, I have tried it with sudo but still, this is what I get,  a bad key!       

[sudo] password for shamininski: 
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
GnuPG passphrase: 
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20170907T033748Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: bad key
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/shamininski/.gnupg/gpg.conf'

Comment: Are you saying that *only your backups* are encrypted? And the rest of your system is not encrypted? Or are you saying that your normal system and your backups are both encrypted but have separate keys?

Comment: @user535733 Yeah, only my backups are encrypted because i chose to encrypt with a key when I turned the duplicity tool on. The rest of the system has a password that i know and use all the time. I hope i have answered you correctly.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Seems like your initial (first) question held much sense. I just navigated to that folder Ctrl+A'd all those files and permanently deleted them then turned off the backup . I pity my ignorance, lol. All the same., thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just remove all the files in the back-up location, encrypted or not. There's no need to know the decryption key or anything about a data set to destroy it.